# How to fix vim throwing error when SHELL is set to xonsh?

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, xonsh

When I start vim I get:

```
Error detected while processing /home/kossak/.vimrc:
line    1: E484: Can't open file /tmp/vdf7WFR/0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My first line in `~/.vimrc` is `let s:uname = system("uname -s")`.

The error happens because `SHELL` env var is set to `/home/kossak/.local/bin/xonsh`. It is set automatically by tmux, because of `set -g default-shell /home/kossak/.local/bin/xonsh` in my `.tmux.conf`. I'd like to manually set `$SHELL` to `/bin/bash`, without changing `default-shell` of tmux. Is it possible?

I know I can run `tmux setenv -g SHELL '/bin/bash'` in CLI and then new panes will have new value, but how to do it in `.tmux.conf`, so tmux does it automatically for me?

I tried adding `setenv -g SHELL '/bin/bash'` to `.tmux.conf` but it doesn't work (the value of `$SHELL` is not changed).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? If you want to use `/home/kossak/.local/bin/xonsh` as your default shell for tmux, why do you *not* want to set SHELL to that?  If that's the shell you want, you should set SHELL to it!  It seems like a simple workaround would be to assign SHELL in the startupfiles for xonsh.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Because when opening file, vim throws an error when in `.vimrc` i have this line `let s:uname = system("uname -s")`. The error is: ```Error detected while processing /home/kossak/.vimrc:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file /tmp/vdf7WFR/0
Press ENTER or type command to continue```
The error instantly disappears when I change SHELL env var back to bash (even when I still run xonsh).

Comment: maybe I should try fixing vim or xonsh, instead of lying to vim that I use bash... But I thought that changing env var was the fastest way, until I realized I can't make tmux do it automatically :)

Comment: And thank you very much for the workaround - I didn't think about it earlier! I set $SHELL in startup file of xonsh and now vim works :) (will see if wrong shell in $SHELL var doesn't break something else).

Comment: sooo just tell vim to use bash? `if executable('bash') set shell=bash endif` - I have this in .vimrc

Comment: ok, it works and it's even better, thank you! Not sure what to do with this question now, maybe I should rephrase it or something... Or just put it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/3396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell vim to prefer bash, to make your vim consistent.

```
if executable('bash')
   set shell=bash
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make `tmux` swap env-vars around, but you can make `xonsh` do it pretty easily, e.g.

```
with ${...}.swap({"SHELL": "/bin/bash"}):
    vim
```

would open `vim` with your environment mutated to set `$SHELL=/bin/bash` but only for the body of the context manager.

You could set this as an alias for `vim` in your `xonshrc`

```
def _vim():
    with ${...}.swap({"SHELL": "/bin/bash"}):
        vim

aliases["vim"] = _vim
```